# Laravel 5.2 - Trying to get property of non-object error on Apache Server

Tags: php, server, laravel-5

I know this question has been asked and answered multiple times but none of the previous post answers my question.

I'm running a website with Laravel 5.2 on an Linux server and get the error :

```
Trying to get property of non-object (View: /mnt/nfs/preprod/greement/htdocs/resources/views/qual_ops/qual_ops_show.blade.php)
```

It works perfectly well with a certain user with WampServer but doesn't on the server (with the same user). Some users also get the error because they are missing a parameter, I'm aware of that.

I checked the databases and files but the only difference is that the tables need to have a capital letter at the beginning of their names (changes made before so the website can run on the server.

Controller - UserQualOpsController.php :

```
public function show($id)
{
    $compte = Compte::find($id);
    $userQualOps = User_qual_ops::join('qual_ops', 'qual_ops.id_qual_ops', '=', 'user_qual_ops.id_qual_ops')
                                    ->join('type_qual_ops', 'type_qual_ops.id_type_qual_ops', '=', 'qual_ops.id_type_qual_ops')
                                    ->where('id_compte', $id)
                                    ->orderBy('type_qual_ops.nom', 'asc')
                                    ->orderBy('qual_ops.code_qual_ops', 'asc')
                                    ->orderBy('date_obtention', 'desc')
                                    ->get();

    $params = [];


    foreach($userQualOps as $userQualOp){
        $params[$userQualOp->id_qual_ops] = Qual_ops_param::where(function($query){
                                                                $query->where('id_organisme', 1)
                                                                    ->orWhere('id_organisme', Auth::user()->id_organisme);
                                                            })
                                                            ->where('id_qual_ops', $userQualOp->id_qual_ops)
                                                            ->first();
    }

    return view('qual_ops/qual_ops_show', [ 'compte' => $compte,
                                            'userQualOps' => $userQualOps,
                                            'params' => $params]);
}
```

View - qual_ops_show.blade.php:

```
@foreach($params as $param)
         ERROR HERE ->  @if($param->id_qual_ops == $userQualOps[$i]->id_qual_ops)
                                <?php
                                    $obtentionDate = Carbon::parse($userQualOps[$i]->date_obtention);
                                    switch($param->premier_seuil_unite){
                                        case 'jour(s)':
                                            $echDatePrem = $obtentionDate->addDay($param->premier_seuil);
                                            break;
                                        case 'mois':
                                            $echDatePrem = $obtentionDate->addMonth($param->premier_seuil);
                                            break;
                                    }
                                    $obtentionDate = Carbon::parse($userQualOps[$i]->date_obtention);

                                    switch($param->deuxieme_seuil_unite){
                                        case 'jour(s)':
                                            $echDateDeux = $obtentionDate->addDay($param->deuxieme_seuil);
                                            break;
                                        case 'mois':
                                            $echDateDeux = $obtentionDate->addMonth($param->deuxieme_seuil);
                                            break;
                                    }
                                    if($echDatePrem->max(Carbon::now()) == $echDatePrem)
                                        $alertNumber = 0;
                                    elseif($echDateDeux->max(Carbon::now()) == $echDateDeux)
                                        $alertNumber = 1;
                                    else
                                        $alertNumber = 2;
                                ?>
                                @if($alertNumber == 2)
                                    <td class="col-md-2">{{Carbon::parse($userQualOps[$i]->date_obtention)->format('d/m/Y')}}<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-alert red-glyphicon float-right"></span></td>
                                @elseif($alertNumber == 1)
                                    <td class="col-md-2">{{Carbon::parse($userQualOps[$i]->date_obtention)->format('d/m/Y')}}<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-alert orange-glyphicon float-right"></span></td>
                                @elseif($alertNumber == 0)
                                    <td class="col-md-2">{{Carbon::parse($userQualOps[$i]->date_obtention)->format('d/m/Y')}}<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok green-glyphicon float-right"></span></td>
                                @endif
                            @endif
                        @endforeach
```

dd($params) :

```
array:16 [▼
    4 => Qual_ops_param {#592 ▼
        #table: "Qual_ops_param"
        #primaryKey: "id_qual_ops_param"
        #fillable: array:5 [▶]
        +timestamps: false
        #connection: null
        #perPage: 15
        +incrementing: true
        #attributes: array:8 [▶]
        #original: array:8 [▶]
        #relations: []
        #hidden: []
        #visible: []
        #appends: []
        #guarded: array:1 [▶]
        #dates: []
        #casts: []
        #touches: []
        #observables: []
        #with: []
        #morphClass: null
        +exists: true
    }
    5 => Qual_ops_param {#586 ▶}
    6 => Qual_ops_param {#411 ▶}
    7 => Qual_ops_param {#407 ▶}
    22 => Qual_ops_param {#589 ▶}
    1 => Qual_ops_param {#412 ▶}
    2 => Qual_ops_param {#585 ▶}
    8 => Qual_ops_param {#581 ▶}
    9 => Qual_ops_param {#580 ▶}
    10 => Qual_ops_param {#578 ▶}
    11 => Qual_ops_param {#591 ▶}
    12 => Qual_ops_param {#576 ▶}
    13 => Qual_ops_param {#584 ▶}
    17 => Qual_ops_param {#574 ▶}
    18 => Qual_ops_param {#573 ▶}
    3 => Qual_ops_param {#590 ▶}
]
```

dd($userQualOps) :

```
Collection {#593 ▼
  #items: array:179 [▼
    0 => User_qual_ops {#594 ▼
      #table: "User_qual_ops"
      #primaryKey: "id_user_qual_ops"
      #fillable: array:5 [ …5]
      +timestamps: false
      #connection: null
      #perPage: 15
      +incrementing: true
      #attributes: array:10 [ …10]
      #original: array:10 [ …10]
      #relations: []
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #appends: []
      #guarded: array:1 [ …1]
      #dates: []
      #casts: []
      #touches: []
      #observables: []
      #with: []
      #morphClass: null
      +exists: true
    }
    1 => User_qual_ops {#595 ▶}
    2 => User_qual_ops {#596 ▶}
    .
    .
    .
```

I'm just trying to understand why does it work on WampServer (because $params is definitely an array) and how to get this thing working on the Linux server.

I can't run the composer/phpartisan on the server and have to work without it.

Comment: Make checks in your view for `is_object()`. You're assuming that all properties should exist and all indexes should be defined.

Comment: worked fine on local & preproduction space, i'll try now with the production one. Thanks a lot. Would you know why it worked localy and not on Linux server ?

Comment: also worked on production space. Thanks again :). You can put your comment as an answer if you want too.

Comment: No need, glad you solved it :)